# Inserting Links between Word and excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have system where I can open a series of word documents and paste the contents on various cells in an excel workbook into bookmarked positions. This is good but I want would rather establish a series of links. How can I adapt my code below to provide the function identified  in the image. Thanks in advance for any help [image: Paste Links]

```
Sub Openword1()
Dim objWord As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ReportFolder As String
Dim ReportName As String
Dim ReportString As String
Dim ReportOpenRef As String


Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data")

For i = 3 To 20
If i = 21 Then
GoTo b:
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ReportFolder = Sheets("Report Information").Range("D1")
ReportName = Sheets("data").Range("a" & i)
ReportString = ReportFolder & ReportName & ".docx"
Sheets("Report Information").Range("D2") = ReportString
ReportOpenRef = ReportName & ".docx"


objWord.Visible = True
objWord.documents.Open ReportString



With objWord.ActiveDocument

.Bookmarks("Ref").Range.Text = ws.Range("B" & i).Text
.Bookmarks("NCP_Reference").Range.Text = ws.Range("C" & i).Text
.Bookmarks("Carpark_Type").Range.Text = ws.Range("H" & i).Text
.Bookmarks("Valuer").Range.Text = ws.Range("P" & i).Text

End With
objWord.documents(ReportOpenRef).Save

objWord.documents.Close

Next i

Set objWord = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
b:


End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried recording the paste action with link in a Word macro? Best to do that then use the [edit] link to include that code in your question. There are various options available and we can't know which you want. Also, press Alt+F9 in the Word document and copy the *field code* that manages the linked information - the text between the { brackets }.

Comment: bookmarks don't have links as far as I know so pasting link is not an option at all, I am trying to figure out what you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Recording a macro reveals the following code for excel to excel. But Excel to word does not record.

Comment: Recording a macro reveals the following code for excel to excel. But Excel to word does not record. ' .Paste Link:=True'. I am trying to now copy the excel cell go to the word doc, select the bookmark and then paste the link using the Paste Link:=True. Is this possible? I am trying to achieve this as it stands to save hours of time. I am regularly required to produce 150+ plus word reports. Many data points in the reports originate in excel so I have created a code to create word reports and paste values. However the numbers change constantly so a link would be preferred.

Comment: If you're adding links, that would ordinarily be a once-off exercise done manually, not 150+ times over. Indeed, your reference to "150+ plus word reports" where "the numbers change constantly" suggests what you really need is a mailmerge.